DESI $Λ$ Constant Results: New physics or better measurements?
Watched this report video here about DESI BAO latest results suggesting a diminishing variable cosmological $Λ$ "constant" and dark energy thus expansion of the universe might slow down especially over the last 7-8 billion years as shown in this diagram of the DESI results provided:

source image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhG56kltfP4
However, could be not really new physics but just more accurate measurements and method. Seems to me that Λ cosmological "constant?" absolute value is pretty much fixed at $1$. The small dip of about $≈0.98$ could just be due to previous measurement methods limitations and inaccuracies. This could be easily verified by using the old methods again and this dip does not show up.
What is the argument against that these are just better more accurate measurements and observations compared to past measurements and methods, and not the result of potentially new physics discovered?

I mean, these measurements do look like they suggest new physics. The argument against new physics is always an experimental flaw/measuring error/more precise measurement, isn’t it?

Judging from the graph, it looks to me that over the last $2$ billion years the Λ value has increased back to $1$ value. This graph does not make any sense to me...

You ask "what is the argument against these being new physics", and that's the argument against these being new physics. There are also arguments for this being new physics, but that seems beyond the scope of the question.
